# How to make a Shader to RGB node in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I need to use the shadows as the factor for something, but I am in cycles because I need real bump displacement. How can I convert a shader to rgb in cycles?

Comment: If you need real bump displacement, you could consider sticking to eevee and adding displacement through a Displacement Modifier, instead of through a shader. Otherwise, in Cycles, I think the best way to add the shadows like that is through the compositor.

Comment: I don't think I can do that because my material is  using multiple noise textures that control both the color and displacement.

Comment: Yeah, I feared that might be the case. I think your best bet then is to bake the shadows and then composite.